# Is : $\frac{dx}{\partial{x}}=1$ and what does it mean :$\frac{{\partial}}{d}$ or $ \frac{d}{\partial} $?

Tags: derivatives, operator-theory, ratio

let $d$ be a total derivative and $\partial$ be the partial derivative with respect to $ x$  , Here i want to know more about these operators and the relationship between them in the context of ratio , then I have two question .

**Question1**:Is  : $\displaystyle\frac{dx}{\partial{x}}=\displaystyle \frac{\partial{x}}{dx}=1$ ?

**Question2:** what it does mean these ratio in mathematics :$\displaystyle\frac{{\partial}}{d}$ or $\displaystyle \frac{d}{\partial} $
are these give us other operator or make no sense in mathematics ?

Comment: They are meaningless symbols, where did you find them?

Comment: What is your definition of a total derivative?